# How do I read a UDP connection until a timeout is reached?

Tags: concurrency, go, network-programming, udp

I need to read UDP traffic until a timeout is reached. I can do this by calling SetDeadline on the UDPConn and looping until I get an I/O timeout error, but this seems hack-ish (flow control based on error conditions). The following code snippet seems more correct, but does not terminate. In production, this would obviously be executed in a goroutine; it's written as a main function for simplicity's sake.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Second * 1):
            fmt.Printf("Finished listening.\n")
            return
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Listening...\n")
            //read from UDPConn here
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the given program terminate? Based on https://gobyexample.com/select, https://gobyexample.com/timeouts, and https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations, I would expect the above code to select the default case for one second, then take the first case and break out of the loop. How might I modify the above snippet to achieve the desired effect of looping and reading until a timeout occurs?

Comment: If you change `break` to `return` the function will complete when the duration does. You are currently looping forever and printing `Finished` every second.

Comment: @chendesheng I believe the use of time.After is idiomatic (see http://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_After)

Thanks to both of you for the catch on the break statement; I've updated the snippet. The program still does not terminate, though

Comment: @chendesheng I forgot to mention: I did try using time.Tick instead, but still got infinite looping behavior

Comment: I was wrong about use time.Tick, it won't help either. And OneOfOne's answer is the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply assign the channel from `time.After` outside the `for` loop, otherwise you will just create a new timer each time you loop.

Example:

```
func main() {
    ch := time.After(time.Second * 1)
L:
    for {
        select {
        case <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("Finished listening.\n")
            break L // have to use a label or it will just break select
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Listening...\n")
            //read from UDPConn here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't work on the playground.

Comment: This works! But why is it necessary? Is the time.After expression being evaluated for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @cqcallaw yes, you were creating a new timer each loop.

Comment: Interesting. Why does this code run as expected, then? Note the "case <-time.After(time.Second * 1)" https://gobyexample.com/timeouts

Comment: @cqcallaw in that example it blocks until either the timer runs out or the channel returns something, adding "default" to `select` makes it nonblocking.

Answer (score 13):

If you are not concerned about read blocking past `n` seconds, then loop until the deadline:

```
 deadline := time.Now().Add(n * time.Second)
 for time.Now().Before(deadline) {
    fmt.Printf("Listening...\n")
    //read from UDPConn here
 }
 fmt.Printf("Finished listening.\n")
```

If you do want to break out of a blocking read after `n` seconds, then set a deadline and read until there's an error:

```
conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(n * time.Second)
for {
   n, err := conn.Read(buf)
   if err != nil {
       if e, ok := err.(net.Error); !ok || !e.Timeout() {
           // handle error, it's not a timeout
       }
       break
   }
   // do something with packet here
}
```

Using a deadline is not hacky. The standard library uses deadlines while reading UDP connections (see the [dns client](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/net/dnsclient_unix.go)).

There are alternatives to using a deadline to break a blocking read: close the connection or send a dummy packet that the reader recognizes. These alternatives require starting another goroutine and are much more complicated than setting a deadline.

Comment: Upvoted for problem-specific knowledge. Do you have an example of where the deadline approach is used in the standard library?

Comment: I'm wishing it was possible to mark multiple answers as answering the question! I feel like OneOfOne's answer still most closely answers the question as asked, but your answer is far more useful in practice. Thank you for the detailed problem-specific info.

Comment: OneOfOne's answer doesn't work on Go 1.19. This should be the accepted answer.