# Golang listenUDP multiple ports blocking with BigTable connection

Tags: go, gcloud, grpc, bigtable

I'm creating a simple udp client that listens on multiple ports and saves the request to bigtable.

It's essential to listen on different ports before you ask.

Everything was working nicely until I included bigtable. After doing so, the listeners block completely.

My stripped down code, without bigtable, looks like this:

```
func flow(port string) {

    protocol := "udp"
    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(protocol, "0.0.0.0:"+port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Wrong Address")
        return
    }

    udpConn, err := net.ListenUDP(protocol, udpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer udpConn.Close()

    for {
        Publish(udpConn, port)
    }
}

func main() {

    fmt.Print("Starting server.........")
    for i := *Start; i <= *End; i++ {
        x := strconv.Itoa(i)
        go flow(x)
    }
}
```

This works fine however, as soon as I add the following for bigtable, the whole thing blocks. If I remove the go routine that creates the listener (which means I can't listen on multiple ports) it works.

```
func createBigTable() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := bigtable.NewClient(ctx, *ProjectID, *Instance)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Bigtable NewClient:", err)
    }

    Table = client.Open("x")

}
```

I managed to get it working by adding a query in the createBigTable func but the program still blocks later on.

I have no idea if this is an issue with bigtable, grpc or just the way I'm doing it.

Would really appreciate some advise about how to fix.

--- UPDATE ---

I've discovered the issue isn't just with BigTable - I also have the same issue when I call gcloud pubsub.

--- UPDATE 2 ---

createBigtable is called in the init function (BEFORE THE MAIN FUNCTION):

```
func init() {
    createBigTable
}
```

--- Update 3 ---

Output from sigquit can be found here:

https://pastebin.com/fzixqmiA

Comment: how do you integrate the "createBigTable" function in flow/main?

Comment: It's in the init function actually with a couple of other things. It's not just BigTable though - adding a connector to PubSub creates the issue too.

Comment: PS. I've moved the call around and it's still interfering.

Comment: I just explained that it's called in the init function which is called before the main function. I've updated regardless.

Comment: Obviously before the main function?

Comment: Yes but I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. Sorry if that sounded like I thought you didn't know what you where doing.
Do you know where exactly the "whole think blocks"?

Comment: If I knew that, I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Jenny: Can you press Ctrl \  (SIG QUIT) while running and get a dump of all Go routines stacks?  That would give a lot of clarity as to what it is blocking on.

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo Thanks, I didn't know you could do this. Think I can see the block, have updated the question.

Comment: Can you provide full runnable code on https://play.golang.org/? So that we can test local.

Comment: @reticentroot not really since I cannot import all the dependancies. However, I've added something here for good measure. https://play.golang.org/p/XeQ0bGcEmt

Comment: I'm still giving it a look... obviously its contained to your flow function, which isn't very big..can you use a timeout or rate limit..perhaps too many connections are being open too fast  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081073/how-do-i-read-a-udp-connection-until-a-timeout-is-reached, I'd also check your machines ulimit and perhaps increase it.. and or also lower the amount of connections being opened.

Comment: Appreciate it. It's not the throttle - it's getting less than 1 per 10 seconds. And it's fine without the gcloud addition.

Comment: Can you use delve to debug... if you don't have delve or have never used it then perhaps you should learn about it... in the mean time place print statements above and below each line of code to figure the exact line that is blocking.. if it can be narrows down to a line or two then the misbehaving function can be pin pointed. I've made some modifications to the example you provide. https://play.golang.org/p/J0FNV33kB0

Comment: Also in your big table function. You create a context with background. Instead create the context with timeout.. Perhaps one of 1 second. You can skip around in this video https://youtu.be/c5ufcpTGIJM but it shows a Google tool being initialized with timeout instead of background. The table could fail to initialize in a timely fashion causing your IO block error in the stack trace you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your playground example, you're using `for {}` to keep the server running for forever.
This seems to deprive the goroutines from ever getting to run.
Try using e.g. a `WaitGroup` to yield control from the `main()` routine and let the `flow()` routines handle the incoming UDP packets.

```
import (
    ...
    "sync"
    ...
)

...

func main() {

    fmt.Print("Starting server.")
    for i := *Start; i <= *End; i++ {
        x := strconv.Itoa(i)
        go flow(x)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Looks like this has sorted it, I cannot test properly but using nc - it works. Thanks !!!!